# Adding quotes to JSON Object in Camel Route

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

I am running into problems when I am trying to unmarshal a JSON string that currently doesn't have quotes around the key-value pairs into a custom POJO.

The Camel route I have defined is:

```
this.from("timer://foo?period=60000")
        .setBody(constant("select * from TEST_TABLE"))
        .to("jdbc:myJDBC")
        .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .split().jsonpath("$[*]").to("log:msg.inbound")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Status.class)
```

And from the log in the route above, I receive the rows of my SQL query as

```
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: {IS_IT_TIME=N, TIME_RECEIVED=1623816000000}]
```

I want the rows instead to be returned with quotes so that I can unmarshal them:

```
Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: {"IS_IT_TIME"="N", "TIME_RECEIVED"=1623816000000}]
```

I have looked around, and seen that there is an option to read unquoted json for Jackson, but I do not want to use this because I am not directly interacting with the ObjectMapper.

If there is a cleaner way to get each row as a JSON object I would interested in this as well. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the Map.class when marshaling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ends up needing this, I used the below to get the result I wanted:

```
this.from("timer://foo?period=60000")
            .setBody(constant(sqlQuery))
            .to("jdbc:myJDBC")
            .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
            .split().jsonpath("$[*]")
            .process(exchange -> {
                String newBody = new ObjectMapper()
                        .writeValueAsString(exchange.getIn().getBody());
                exchange.getIn().setBody(newBody);
            })
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, Status.class)
```

Inside the process, we are able to process the body of the message using the writeValueAsString method (supplied by an instance of ObjectMapper), and then set the returned body to be this String. The String newBody consists of the JSON object with quotes.